# C# UWP Resolve DNS

Tags: c#, windows, dns, uwp

In UWP (Windows 10) how to check and resolve DNS conflicts?

I have found this for finding DNS address:

```
HostName host = new HostName("www.google.com");
var eps = await DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync(host, "80");
```

How to check if there are any conflicts with DNS? How to set DNS settings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To check for conflicts you'll need to look at all records, not just what's used when making a single request.
If you want to get the DNS settings you'll need to retrieve all the settings for a record. The easiest way I've found to do this is with [dns-api.org](https://dns-api.org/) where you can make requests like https://dns-api.org/A/stackoverflow.com

To change DNS settings will be dependent upon where they're set.